# RAILS or in if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure how to use the OR in a view IF statement.

This doesn't work:

```
<% if current_user.employee.emptype.typename == "ADMIN" or "TECH" %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write something like this :

```
<% if current_user.employee.emptype.typename == "ADMIN" || current_user.employee.emptype.typename == "TECH" %>
```

Or better

```
<% if ['TECH', 'ADMIN'].include?(current_user.employee.emptype.typename) %>
```

Be careful with OR and AND keywords, they don't have same operators priority than `&&` and `||`

Comment: @Reddirt See the answer of awendt, he follows a useful link to understand the difference between && and and.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one of two ways. I prefer the first method.

```
<% if current_user.employee.emptype.typename.in?(["ADMIN", "TECH"]) %>
```

...or...

```
<% if current_user.employee.emptype.typename == "ADMIN" || current_user.employee.emptype.typename == "TECH" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, and it has nothing to do with views. In Ruby, all strings evaluate to `true` in if statements.

You have to check both values against the type name, like so:

```
if current_user.employee.emptype.type_name == "ADMIN" || current_user.employee.emptype.type_name == "TECH"
```

or check if it's contained within an array of valid types:

```
if ["ADMIN", "TECH"].include?(current_user.employee.emptype.type_name)
```

Please also see [this article](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) for a comparison of `||` and `or` in Ruby.